# How to use postgres user in a shell script on Ubuntu 16

Tags: postgresql, shell, ubuntu, psql

I am trying to adapt a shell script set made for running on Debian 7 to work on Ubuntu 16.

I got to change successfully all except a part that executes PosgreSQL database commands.

Former version of script has these lines:

```
service postgresql restart

psql -q -U postgres -c "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS db_crm" -o $log &> /dev/null
psql -q -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE db_crm" -o $log &> /dev/null
```

When I tried to run psql as above on Ubuntu 16, OS didn't recognize command. It is important to say that script is called with sudo.

I got to find a way to run only database script on Ubuntu 16 changing code so:

```
service postgresql restart

su postgres <<EOF

psql -c "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS db_crm" -o $log &> /dev/null
psql -c "CREATE DATABASE db_crm" -o $log &> /dev/null
```

However, this same script doesn't work when it is called by main script. Following messages are presented:

```
here-document at line 41 delimited by end-of-file (wanted 'EOF')

syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Even replacing EOF to beggining of next line, error continues.

If there is a way to use psql in shell script without to use EOF would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your script is failing, is you forgot the `EOF` at the end of input.

```
su postgres <<EOF

psql -c "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS db_crm" -o $log &> /dev/null
psql -c "CREATE DATABASE db_crm" -o $log &> /dev/null

EOF   #<<<--- HERE
```

An easy way to do this is to put your commands into a temporary file, then re-direct that into `psql`.  Obviously you don't want this to stop for a password prompt, in this case either use a user that doesn't need it, or set `$PGPASSWORD` - or prompt at the beginning of the script - there's lots of ways around.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# PGPASSWORD='' #(set this to stop password prompts, but it's insecure)
PSQL="psql -q -U postgres -o $log"  #TODO define $log
TMPFILE="/tmp/sql-tmp.`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%N`.sql"

# TODO - check $TMPFILE does not exist already

echo "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS db_crm;" > "$TMPFILE"
echo "CREATE DATABASE db_cr;" >> "$TMPFILE"
# ... etc.

# run the command, throw away any stdout, stderr
PSQL < "$TMPFILE" 2>&1 > /dev/null

# exit with the psql error code
err_code=$?
exit $?
```